# Injectivity of given integer function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have a function $g: \mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+- \{(x,x)\} \to \mathbb{Z}^+$ that is defined using another function $f:\mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}^+$, this way: $g(a,b) = f(\max(a,b)) - f(\min(a,b))$ where $\max(a,b)\not= \min(a,b)$. What are the neccessary and sufficient conditions on $f$ so that $g$ is injective?

For instance, using $f(x)=2^x$ has the properties I need since expressing the numbers in binary gives an easy proof that the difference of two powers of two is always different if the exponent are different.

The problem is this function grows too fast, I would like to find some other $f$ with the same property but that grows slower. If we restrict the domain to positive integers smaller than 1000, the function $f(x)=x^5$ does the trick, but $f(x)=x^4$, $f(x)=x^3$, $f(x)=x^2$, $f(x)=x$ do not. I would like to analyse this problem in a more rigourous manner. If you guys know some references about any similar problem with solutions I will be glad to hear. If you find out a proof that using any polynomial is impossible to construct an injective $g$, that would be helpful too.

Comment: Note that $g(a,a) = 0$ for any integer $a$, so the codomain doesn't seem right and you'll need more conditions on the domain to have any hope of injectivity.  Also, you switched from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ in the function definitions to nonnegative integers later.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the zero is more or less irrelevant. You can ignore it in the domain and codomain, I am only interested in the injectivity for pairs that contain two different numbers. That's why I use nonnegative and positive indistinguisable, because in practice it doesn't matter for my problem. I have added the zero everywhere so that it is not confusing anymore.

Comment: Adding $0$ to domain/codomain won't help you, $g$ still won't be injective as the example above $g(a,a)=0$ shows. For another counterexample consider $g(1,2)=f(2)-f(1)=g(2,1)$. Also with $f$ strictly increasing, notice that $g(a,b)=|f(a)−f(b)|$ defines the same thing.

Comment: Just ignore the zero case, it is not what I really want. I'll remove the zero from the codomain, and the line (x,x) from the domain. That is a trivial counterexample I am not interested in.

Comment: I just want something that grows slower than the exponential. Or a proof that it is impossible to find such function for instance in the space of polynomials. The exponential is a positive example, so please, try stopping to indicate that it is imposible to find such a function, because it is, indeed, possible.

Comment: Problem is it's unclear what you are asking for (maybe there is misunderstanding about what injectivity is). The example you provide doesn't work: For $f(x)=2^x$ you have $g(1,2)=2^2-2^1=2$ but also $g(2,1)=2^2-1^2=2$, so $g(1,2)=g(2,1)$ but $(1,2)\neq(2,1)$, hence $g$ is not injective.

Comment: Your example with binary representation explains what you want, but it is not injectivity, well unless the domain only contains $(a,b)$ with $a<b$ for example (in which case you don't need the min/max anyway). Or drop the injectivity requirement altogether and replace it exactly with what you want (seems to me you want $f$'s such that $|f(a)-f(b)|=|f(c)-f(d)|$ implies $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$, or something along that lines)

Comment: @Sil, yes, that's exactly what I want, but since your answer is good enough for me I will leave it as that. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you find out a proof that using any polynomial is impossible to construct an injective $g$, that would be helpful too.

If you want $g(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ to be unique for only one pair of integers $0<x<y$, then this is not possible for quadratic polynomials $f(x)$ (and hence also linear or constant polynomials).

Put $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, then
$$
f(x)-f(u)=f(y)-f(v)\tag{*}
$$
and after multiplication by $4a$ and completing the squares, this implies
$$
(2ax+b)^2-(2au+b)^2=(2ay+b)^2-(2av+b)^2.
$$
Now $X^2-U^2=Y^2-V^2$ has some known parametrizations, we have
$$
(k(pr+sq))^2-(k(pr-qs))^2=(k(ps+qr))^2-(k(qr-ps))^2.
$$
So choosing the parameters such that all terms inside the squares are $\equiv b\pmod {2a}$, we can transform it to our more general quadratic. So for example let $P,Q,R,S,K\in \mathbb{Z}$, then
$$
p=2aP+1,q=2aQ+1,r=2aR+1,s=2aS,k=2aK+b
$$
allows us to set
$$
x=\frac{k(pr+qs)-b}{2a},v=\frac{k(ps+qr)-b}{2a},u=\frac{k(pr-qs)-b}{2a},y=\frac{k(qr-ps)-b}{2a}
$$
which then satisfies $(*)$ (and everything ends up an integer). Some additional restrictions might be added to ensure that all values end up positive (or apply absolute values).

As an illustration let's say we have $f(x)=3x^2+x+1$, then $a=3,b=1,c=1$ and for example $P=2,Q=1,R=2,S=1,K=1$ in the above gives
$$f(246)-f(148)=f(197)-f(15)=115934.$$

It is possible that similar argument can be found for degrees three and four, but already for degree five this is an open problem for $f(x)=x^5$. Specifically it is not known whether there is a solution to $x^5+y^5=u^5+v^5$ with $\{x,y\}\neq\{u,v\}$, so we simply don't know whether $x^5-u^5=y^5-v^5$ is possible non-trivially (no example has yet been found). See also [Generalized taxicab number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_taxicab_number) .

Comment: For the case of the fifth power, do you know if it is related to the reason why polynomials of order 5 do not have formula for roots? Because it looks like much of a coincidence that we know the solution for cases n<5, like we did with the roots of polynomials of degrees n<5.

Comment: @J.P.C. I was wondering the same but I don't know. It seems to me that if there was a connection, then it would be already used as a proof of the open problem or some progress. Plus, we don't really know if degree 3 or 4 are possible or not, maybe there is an example there that works. I think $x^4+x^3+x^2+x$ yielded only one counterexample when I checked.

Comment: for that polynomial there are two counterexamples (although they are only really one as you said) for integers less than 3000, which are $f(197)-f(52)=f(249)-f(220)$ and $f(220)-f(52)=f(249)-f(197)$. Interesting. It all seems quite arbitrary, without any kind of pattern.